# Can I get vim to show the current function/namespace/etc. in the bottom bar?

Tags: vim, namespaces, text-editor

I love the sorts of features that applications like textedit and sublime edit have, where you can see the current namespace in a little bar in the UI. Is there any way to make vim do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Powerline](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3881) plugin shows the current function.

Answer (score 0):

Would [TagBar](http://majutsushi.github.com/tagbar/) or [TagList](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) help? Both provide a small function to add to your statusline to that effect. Or maybe [this other plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2055)?

I'm not fan of that kind of feature. I prefer to use `<C-w>}` when I need.

Answer (score 0):

here's a one-liner you can put in your .vimrc   (need to have taglist.vim installed though):

```
set statusline=%<%f\ [%{Tlist_Get_Tagname_By_Line()}]\ %h%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
```

...that'll show the current function your cursor is in as you move around.

I forget the specifics but sometimes you'll want to manually refresh it, in which case this mapping is useful:

```
map <F4> :TlistUpdate<CR>:TlistHighlightTag<CR>
```

^ that'll refresh the function name in your statusline when you press F4